# Problem Deploying a Next JS + Sanity Project to Vercel

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel, sanity

I was on a project and used nextjs with sanity but after almost finishing my project, I just don't see any way to deploy it. Learning sanity took quite a bit of time but what meaning is there if I can't use it anywhere.

I installed vercel and ran `vercel build` this is what it shows me:

```
[17:27:01.100] Retrieving list of deployment files...
[17:27:01.382] Previous build cache not available
[17:27:01.637] Downloading 75 deployment files...
[17:27:02.283] Running "vercel build"
[17:27:02.784] Vercel CLI 28.10.0
[17:27:03.095] Installing dependencies...
[17:27:11.072] 
[17:27:11.073] added 229 packages in 8s
[17:27:11.073] 
[17:27:11.073] 32 packages are looking for funding
[17:27:11.073]   run `npm fund` for details
[17:27:11.086] Detected Next.js version: 13.0.7
[17:27:11.089] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
[17:27:11.089] Running "npm run build"
[17:27:11.396] 
[17:27:11.396] > ptfolio@0.1.0 build
[17:27:11.396] > next build
[17:27:11.396] 
[17:27:11.838] Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
[17:27:11.839] This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
[17:27:11.839] You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
[17:27:11.839] https://nextjs.org/telemetry
[17:27:11.839] 
[17:27:11.968] info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
[17:27:15.476] Failed to compile.
[17:27:15.476] 
[17:27:15.476] ./sanity/sanity.cli.ts:1:31
[17:27:15.477] Type error: Cannot find module 'sanity/cli' or its corresponding type declarations.
[17:27:15.477] 
[17:27:15.477] [0m[31m[1m>[22m[39m[90m 1 | [39m[36mimport[39m {defineCliConfig} [36mfrom[39m [32m'sanity/cli'[39m[0m
[17:27:15.477] [0m [90m   | [39m                              [31m[1m^[22m[39m[0m
[17:27:15.477] [0m [90m 2 | [39m[0m
[17:27:15.477] [0m [90m 3 | [39m[36mexport[39m [36mdefault[39m defineCliConfig({[0m
[17:27:15.477] [0m [90m 4 | [39m  api[33m:[39m {[0m
[17:27:15.520] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

And I have tried installing sanity cli, sanity client, sanity image url, tried pushing into github and deploy from there. Don't know what to do anymore

Edit: here's my pakage.json file->

```
{
  "name": "ptfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.13",
    "@next/font": "13.0.7",
    "@portabletext/react": "^2.0.0",
    "@sanity/cli": "^3.1.2",
    "@sanity/client": "^3.4.1",
    "@sanity/image-url": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/node": "18.11.16",
    "@types/react": "18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.9",
    "framer-motion": "^7.10.2",
    "git": "^0.1.5",
    "next": "13.0.7",
    "next-sanity": "^3.1.8",
    "next-sanity-image": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.41.1",
    "react-simple-typewriter": "^5.0.1",
    "react-social-icons": "^5.15.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.20",
    "tailwind-scrollbar": "^2.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show packages.json file ?

Comment: @Honorablecon
I added my pakage.json file

Comment: @TheFlashExs did you ever find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that sanity/cli dependency is not install globaly or in devDependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution, i had the same problem.

Add some Environnement Variable (into the Vercel Project go to Setting) :

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID
```

and

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL
```

With the right value.

Don't forget the "https://" for the url.

Let me know if it solve the problem on your side

Answer (score 0):

create .vercelignore inside root directory
and add
sanity